# Getting SUM of two distinct procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two procedures that calculate two data. Now i would like to get the sum of those two output. Is it possible in sql?

ex:

```
Select bio.*, 
SUM (cnt_report,cnt_report_2) as TOTAL --CAN I DO THIS?
cnt_report + cnt_report_2 as Total --This doesn't seem to work
from biographical bio
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cr.id, COUNT (*) AS cnt_report
    FROM   report cr
    GROUP BY cr.id
  ) cr11 ON bio.id = cr11.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cr.id2,
    COUNT (*) AS cnt_report_2
    FROM   report cr
    GROUP BY cr.id2
  ) cr11 ON bio.id = cr11.id2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sum function will work with a little tweak, but you will need to add a GROUP BY line at the end. Also, you seem to have named your two sub queries with the same alias. Try this:

```
Select bio.*, 
SUM (cr11_1.cnt_report + cr11_2.cnt_report_2) as TOTAL
from biographical bio
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cr.id, COUNT (*) AS cnt_report
    FROM   report cr
    GROUP BY cr.id
  ) cr11_1 ON bio.id = cr11_1.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT cr.id2,
    COUNT (*) AS cnt_report_2
    FROM   report cr
    GROUP BY cr.id2
  ) cr11_2 ON bio.id = cr11_2.id2
GROUP BY bio.*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this:

```
sum(something, something_else)
```

but you can do this:

```
sum(something + something_else)
```

You can figure out how to implement that into your query.   Remember that if you are selecting other fields along with an aggregate, you need a group by clause.